# Apply CSS class to the body when opening a menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, lit-element, lit

I'm currently working on a web project using LitElement, and I have a menu that shows when I click the hamburguer button, and closes when I click the close button or navigate to other page.

My problem is that I want to apply the CSS property `overflow: hidden;` in order to stop the scroll for the rest of the page (because my menu has 100% width and height), and remove that property when the menu is closed.

When I click the menu button, the component `Menu` is created, and when I click the close button (or navigate to another page) the component is deleted, so I have to apply the `overflow` in one component and remove it on another.

So, my question is, how to do that?

Comment: Zero experience with lit, but can't you just `addEventListener` to the open button to add class to body, and another `addEventListener` to the close button to remove it ?

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `addEventListener` like me below.

```js
document.querySelector('.burger').addEventListener('click', () => {
   document.body.classList.toggle('activeBurger');
})
```

```css
.activeBurger {
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<button class="burger"></button>
```

Comment: You're guessing at a solution here as we don't have enough information to give specific answers. It's best to ask for clarity first.

Comment: Didn't work, but thanks for trying to help.

Comment: now it work, i wrote bad name in css